# API returning empty payload on live server but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

[This is the response I get using the localhost API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyD6E.png)

[This is the response I get using the staging API deployed on Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpwST.png)

This is how I'm calling the API

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const getSandboxKey = async () => {
    
        const config = {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        };
    
        const response = await axios.get(
          `API_URL/api/v1/organization/get-sandbox-keys`,
          config
        );
    
        setData(response.data.payload[0]);
      };

         getSandboxKey();
       }, []);

return (
<div>{data.secretKey}</div>
<div>{data.publicKey}</div>
<div>{data.mode}</div>
)
```

I'm trying to get some data from the payload. It works perfectly on localhost

Comment: This appears to be an issue with your API or production environment, not react. We'd need details about your API or environment to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would check if the token might be the issue here. Some questions you might look into:

- How do you save the token?
- Can the same token be used for both localhost and staging? Or should they be different?
- Did you refresh the (maybe cached) token before testing staging?